# create importer with importer api

Tags: import, api

I want create new custom importer but I don't know which way is best

I googled and find out wordpress has an importer api but there isn't no tutorial and reference

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have no privileges to comment so just providing links here in answer, may this helps you:

[Tutorial part 1](http://www.washington.edu/marketing/web/write-a-custom-wordpress-importer-part-1/)

[Tutorial Part 2](http://www.washington.edu/marketing/web/write-a-custom-wordpress-importer-part-2/)

Similar question:

[How to Create Export/Import Functionality for Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63232/how-to-create-export-import-functionality-for-plugin)

Thanks!